# Drools Fusion Out of Order events

Tags: drools, drools-fusion, drools-kie-server

I am using Drools fusion for processing real time events. Each event has a timestamp field.
Issue is events can be out of order sometimes. Can drools fusion handle this situtation and if yes how ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If A is stamped 0:00:00 and B is stamped 0:01:00 and B arrives and you have the rule

```
rule "A before B"
when
    $b: B()
    not A( this before $b )
then ... end
```

it will fire.

You can use fact insertion time as a timestamp.

Keep the original timestamp as a property. Maybe you'll want to look at it if a "situation" occurs. It depends.

**Addition** If you have a maximum delay dt you can put all arriving events into "quarantine" for this delay. Before you insert A, check all other streams (sources) for an event B that precedes A and react accordingly. Everything will react at least delayed by dt.

Comment: so on inserting B rule will fire and won't wait for A since A already occured and is out of order so can we specify any wait time till that it waits for delayed events or so ?Else it will be a problem

Comment: I have added another suggestion. This would be something you'll have to implement.

Comment: so I have to maintain custom repository where I hold events for dt time and then insert in kie session .Is that you are suggesting ?

Comment: Also do you have any idea/sample code on serializing user's session data out of kiesession ?Is it possible to do so ?

Comment: I wouldn't call it "repository", but yes. What else? - Serializing is another topic, but: just get it all (API method!) and serialize it

Comment: get it all means all session will be serialized or can only single fact be serialized.

Comment: If you want to serialize the data it is up to you: you can get the facts/objects from Working Memory and serialize them.